# About the relation between a tetrahedra and spheres moving in a tetrahedra

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polyhedra

I found the following question in a book:

There exists a regular triangle $OAB$ which has edge-length $2$. Let $H, I, J$ be a foot of the perpendicular line drawn from a point $P$ in $OAB$ to the edge $OA, AB, BO$ respectively. Also, let $C, D, E$ be a circle whose diameter is $PH, PI, PJ$ respectively. Then, find the area of the region where $P$ can move such that the interiors of each $C, D, E$ lie within the interior of $OAB$.

This question is easy to solve. Then, I'm interested in the third-version of this question. Here is my question.

**Question**: There exists a regular tetrahedron $ABCD$. Let $H_A, H_B, H_C, H_D$ be a foot of the perpendicular line drawn from a point $P$ in $ABCD$ to the face $BCD, ACD, ABD, ABC$ respectively. Then, let $V_{12}$ be the volume of the region where $P$ can move such that $P$ satisfies $(1), (2)$. Also, let $V_{2}$ be the volume of the region where $P$ can move such that $P$ satisfies $(2)$. Then, find ${V_{12}}/{V_2}$. Here,

(1) The interiors of each sphere whose diameter is $PH_A, PH_B, PH_C, PH_D$ lie within the interior of $ABCD$.

(2) $PH_A\le PH_B\le PH_C\le PH_D$.

I've got the following : $\frac{PH_D}{PH_A}$ can be any value in $1 \le \frac{PH_D}{PH_A} \le 3$.

However, I'm facing difficulty. Could you show me how to get the result?

Comment: What does it mean for a circle/sphere to be "included in or on" a triangle/tetrahedron? Presumably, "included *in*" means that the circle/sphere lies entirely inside the triangle/tetrahedron; but what about "included *on*"?

Comment: BTW: A reference to the book (title and author) would be nice, so that the author gets credit for the question. Moreover, if we know the book, we might be able to point to helpful sections of it; if we *don't* know the book, we might want to find it and read it. :)

Comment: @Blue: Thank you for pointing it out. As you wrote, "included in" means that the circle/sphere lies entirely inside the triangle/tetrahedron. I used "included on" for representing that each can come in contact with circle/sphere. I'm not sure that "included on" is included in "included in", so I used this expression. If "included in" means also that "they can come in contact with circle/sphere", then I'll delete "on".

Comment: @Blue: (part2)sorry, but I don't have the book because I read it a few years ago and I don't know other information. Also, I must say what I found in the book is only the second-version question, and the 3rd version question is the question I made because of my interest.

Comment: I think "included in" alone would be fine. Alternatively, you could re-phrase as something like "The interiors of the circles lie within the interior of the triangle."

Comment: @Blue: Thank you. I edited it.